# iostat returns disk utilization greater than 100% while profiling a Beaglebone Black board

Tags: linux, dd, block-device, beagleboneblack, iostat

I need to profile the performance of software running on a BeagleBone Black (BBB). The BBB has an ARM Cortex-A8 up to 1GHz frequency, 512MB RAM, and 4GB eMMC onboard flash storage. You can find more information here:
https://beagleboard.org/black

The BBB runs Debian bullseye booted from a 14GB MicroSD:

```
debian@BeagleBone:~$ uname -a
Linux BeagleBone 5.10.109-ti-r45 #1bullseye SMP PREEMPT Fri May 6 16:59:02 UTC 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

### Problem

As first trial, I'm running in parallel `iostat` with `dd`:

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=~debian/ddtest/200MBfile bs=1M count=200 & iostat -xdz 1 20`

I don't understand why `iostat` returns utilization values greater then 100%. I'm getting the metrics each second specifying `1` as argument in the command line. This is an excerpt of what I see in the terminal:

```
Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util

mmcblk0          0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00   18.00   9216.00     0.00   0.00 1062.00   512.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00   19.12  92.80 

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util

mmcblk0          0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00   16.00   8192.00     7.00  30.43 2058.25   512.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00   32.93 101.20 

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util

mmcblk0          0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00   25.00  12800.00     0.00   0.00 2295.64   512.00    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00   57.39 103.60

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util

mmcblk0          0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00   33.00  15908.00     0.00   0.00 1136.58   482.06    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00   37.51  89.60
```

`mmcblk0` is the name of the 14GB memory (as stated by `lsblk`).

I downloaded `sysstat`, namely the package including `iostat`, directly from https://packages.debian.org/stable/sysstat and installed the version `12.5.2-2`:

`sudo apt list | grep sysstat sysstat/stable,now 12.5.2-2 armhf [residual-config]`

I checked the source code of `sysstat` and I saw that the utilization is calculated at line `381` of `rd_stats.c`:
`xds→util = S_VALUE(spd→tot_ticks, sdc→tot_ticks, itc);`

`S_VALUE` is a MACRO defined at line `154` of `common.h`:
`#define S_VALUE(m,n,p) (((double) ((n) - (m))) / (p) * 100)`

Each second `iostat` reads the `ms` spent doing I/O from `/proc/diskstats`. The variable `sdc->tot_ticks` represents the last value read, `sdp->tot_ticks` the previous sampled value, while `itc` is the sampling interval we set from the command line (i.e., one second).

I can't understand why `iostat` returns values greater than 100%. I noticed that the time spent doing I/O (`sdc->tot_ticks - sdp->tot_ticks`) is often greater than `itc`. My guess is that `iostat` performs disk operations, that `dd` is preempted by the scheduler between two `/proc/diskstat` sampling or there are some processes running in parallel.

### Experiments

I did some experiments, but I'm still don't get the source of the problem.

With `iotop`, I checked what processes were running concurrently with `dd`. I found a few journaling processes, i.e., jb2 and systemdjournald. They do not affect disk utilization, since the time indicated at the 10th field of `/proc/diskstats` records the time queues and disks were busy, taking concurrency into account (https://serverfault.com/questions/862334/interpreting-read-write-and-total-io-time-in-proc-diskstats).

I made a trivial bash script (attached to this paragraph) that mimics the behavior of `iostat`. It retrieves the 10th field from `/proc/diskstats` and calculates the utilization given an observation time. I set an observation period of 1 second, the same as my first attempt with `iostat`, and obtained a utilization of more than 100%. I believe that `iostat` is not the problem, as confirmed by this issue:
https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues/73#issuecomment-860158402

Using the bash script, I got even higher values than those received from `iostat`. I believe this is due to `/proc/diskstats` readings or BBB performance extending the execution time of the script (or `iostat`).

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=0; i<$2; i++ ));
do
  value=$(cat "/proc/diskstats" | awk '/ mmcblk0 / {print $13}')
  if [ ! -z "$prev" ]; then
    bc -l <<< "scale=4;(($value - $prev)/($1*1000))*100"
  fi
  sleep $1
  prev=$value
done
```

I observed that running `dd` with the `oflag=sync` option decreases disk utilization. Also, journaling processes are not executed at the same time as `dd` but after it. This flag blocks the writing process until it is actually written to the device. This is the output of `perf` recording  who makes block I/O requests:

`sudo perf record -e block:block_rq_insert -a dd if=/de/urandom of=~debian/ddtest/500MBfile bs=1M count=200`

without `oflag=sync`

[image: without oflag=sync]

with `oflag=sync`

[image: with oflag=sync]

I'm missing how the kernel updates `/proc/diskstats`. I hope someone more experienced than me on the platform can help me understand the problem. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't get any decent solution here, you might want to raise this directly on the sysstat github issues page, https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues?q=is%3Aissue

Comment: Hi @steve, thank you for your answer. I updated the question with some experiments. I hope this can help you to figure out what's happening :).